# How to addClass() to the pictures of a certain format

Tags: jquery, image, format, containers, jpeg

### Hi, I need to style images of a JPG format only. (jQuery)

I need class to be applied to jpeg's when it's placed in specific container (not all jpg's on the page).
For example:

```
<img src="non-jpeg.jpg"> <!--no changes made-->
<img src="jpeg-image.jpg"> <!--no changes made-->
<div class="spec-container"><img src="jpeg-image.jpg"></div> <!--changes applied-->
```

to be like this

```
<img src="non-jpeg.jpg">
<img src="jpeg-image.jpg">
<div class="spec-container"><img src="jpeg-image.jpg" class="styled"></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using an [attribute-ends-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) for images inside that container, like this:

```
$(".spec-container img[src$='.jpg']").addClass("styled");
```

If you want the selector a bit more forgiving, use `.filter()` like this:

```
$(".spec-container img").filter(function() {
  return /\.[jpg$|jpeg$]/i.test(this.src);
}).addClass("styled");
```

Comment: +1 but maybe add `.jpeg` in the mix for completeness' sake. Also, is this case insensitive?

Comment: Oh and congratulations to breaking the 100k barrier!

Comment: @Pekka - updated to handle the various cases and thanks :) @dessol - you can modify the regex I have above for any additional formats.

Comment: Hi again. It became necessary to assign classes only for those images that are larger than 10px
How can I add this feature? Many thanks in advance

Comment: @dessol - please open a new question for that...it's completely unrelated to this one, we want to try and keep each question on topic so it's a much better google resource later :)  Link me here and I'll certainly take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

You can just do that with pure CSS. Put the class="styled" on all your images, then in the CSS:

```
img.styled
{
    /* put styles that apply to non-styled images here */
}

div.spec-container img.styled
{
    /* put styles here that you want only applied to the "styled" images */
}
```

Comment: ... and I need curtain jpg format to be styled only. CSS doesn't provide me with that option